# Is the collection of sFlow packets through TSDR feature available in Opendaylight Oxygen?

Tags: opendaylight

The Opendaylight *TSDR User Guide* (https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/user-guide/tsdr-user-guide.html#installing-tsdr-data-collectors) shows an **sFlow Collector feature** available for installing, but is not showed in the actual list of features of my Opendaylight controller.

```
opendaylight-user@root>feature:list|grep tsdr
odl-tsdr-openflow-statistics-collector           │ 1.5.1            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-tsdr-1.5.1                                   │ OpenDaylight :: TSDR :: Openflow Statistics Colle
features-tsdr                                    │ 1.5.1            │          │ Uninstalled │ features-tsdr                                    │ ODL :: tsdr :: features-tsdr
odl-tsdr-hsqldb-all                              │ 1.5.1            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-tsdr-1.5.1                                   │ ODL :: tsdr :: hsqldb all
odl-tsdr-cassandra                               │ 1.5.1            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-tsdr-1.5.1                                   │ OpenDaylight :: TSDR :: Cassandra Persistence
odl-tsdr-elasticsearch                           │ 1.5.1            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-odl-sdni-aggregator-1.5.1                    │ OpenDaylight :: TSDR :: ElasticSearch Persistence
odl-tsdr-hsqldb                                  │ 1.5.1            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-tsdr-1.5.1                                   │ ODL :: tsdr :: HSQLDB
odl-hbaseclient                                  │ 1.5.1            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-tsdr-1.5.1                                   │ ODL :: tsdr :: odl-hbaseclient
odl-tsdr-syslog-collector                        │ 1.5.1            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-odl-sdni-aggregator-1.5.1                    │ OpenDaylight :: TSDR :: Syslog Collector
odl-tsdr-netflow-statistics-collector            │ 1.5.1            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-tsdr-1.5.1                                   │ OpenDaylight :: TSDR :: Netflow Statistics Collec
odl-tsdr-restconf-collector                      │ 1.5.1            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-tsdr-1.5.1                                   │ OpenDaylight :: TSDR :: Restconf Collector
odl-tsdr-hbase                                   │ 1.5.1            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-tsdr-1.5.1                                   │ OpenDaylight :: TSDR :: HBase Persistence
odl-tsdr-core                                    │ 1.5.1            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-tsdr-1.5.1                                   │ OpenDaylight :: TSDR :: Core
```

I wonder if the collection of sFlow packets is supported by default, because its model still is in *collectors* folder (https://github.com/opendaylight/tsdr/tree/master/collectors), but not in *features* folder (https://github.com/opendaylight/tsdr/tree/master/features)

Answer (score 2):

The sFlow collector is not installed by default.  You made a good evaluation. I saw your post on the tsdr-dev@lists.opendaylight.org list.  We will respond there with more detail if needed.

The TSDR sFlow collector feature was disabled and not migrated during a framework change due to some integration CSIT test failures.  The code is there as you see (./tsdr/collectors/sflow-statistics-collector) and can be added to the (./tsdr/features/sflow-statistics-collector) directory like the rest of the TSDR features.  It should work in a stand alone build, it was only failing the CSIT tests in the integration/release build.  We did not have the cycles to fix the tests at that time. There are several folks who are interested in adding it back, so if you would like to attend the weekly ODL TSDR meeting and voice your interest we might be able to schedule it in the Flourine release or the next release cycle. [1]  OpenDaylight weekly meeting calander [2]

[1]  ODL TSDR Weekly meeting, 2-3pm PST Wednesday  https://zoom.us/j/850334971

[2]  https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=aDc5aGltYm9rcThhYXVyOWxlZDhvYzc5MGdAZ3JvdXAuY2FsZW5kYXIuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ

Comment: Hmm. This answer will probably not be useful beyond the immediate. Maybe this should have been a comment on the OP.